# Out of four std::vector objects select the one with the most elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector

I have four std::vector containers that all might (or might not) contain elements. I want to determine which of them has the most elements and use it subsequently.

I tried to create a std::map with their respective sizes as keys and references to those containers as values. Then I applied std::max on the size() of each vector to figure out the maximum and accessed it through the std::map.

Obviously, this gets me into trouble once there is the same number of elements in at least two vectors.

Can anyone think of a elegant solution ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're severely overthinking this.  You've only got four vectors.  You can determine the largest vector using 3 comparisons.  Just do that:

```
std::vector<blah>& max = vector1;
if (max.size() < vector2.size()) max = vector2;
if (max.size() < vector3.size()) max = vector3;
if (max.size() < vector4.size()) max = vector4;
```

### EDIT:

Now with pointers!

<s>EDIT (280Z28):</s>

Now with references! :)

### EDIT:

The version with references won't work.  Pavel Minaev explains it nicely in the comments:

> That's correct, the code use
>   references. The first line, which
>   declares max, doesn't cause a copy.
>   However, all following lines do cause
>   a copy, because when you write `max =
>   vectorN`, if max is a reference, it
>   doesn't cause the reference to refer
>   to a different vector (a reference
>   cannot be changed to refer to a
>   different object once initialized).
>   Instead, it is the same as
>   `max.operator=(vectorN)`, which simply
>   causes `vector1` to be cleared and
>   replaced by elements contained in
>   `vectorN`, copying them.

The pointer version is likely your best bet: it's quick, low-cost, and simple.

```
std::vector<blah> * max = &vector1;
if (max->size() < vector2.size()) max = &vector2;
if (max->size() < vector3.size()) max = &vector3;
if (max->size() < vector4.size()) max = &vector4;
```

Comment: I would use pointers though, to avoid the copying here. Better yet, a reference – but that entails doing all the above comparisons in the initialization.

Comment: I agree with not over-thinking the problem, but your example might copy the contents of each of the four vectors into the `max` vector. Depending on how one wishes to use the vector, I'd recommend a pointer (or a const pointer) to avoid copying.

Comment: @Konrad: I didn't know the specifics of his situation, so I provided a basic example.  Tailoring it to use pointers is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: There, are you people happy now?!

Comment: Thanks... yep I was waaaay overthinking it.. :-)

Comment: No, because if `vector4` is the largest, you're still doing 2 potentially very expensive copies (lines 2-3).

Comment: @Pavel: The code uses references. The size checks are more expensive than the copies.

Comment: That's correct, the code use references. The first line, which declares `max`, doesn't cause a copy. However, all following lines do cause a copy, because when you write `max = vectorN`, if `max` is a reference, it doesn't cause the reference to refer to a different vector (a reference cannot be changed to refer to a different object once initialized). Instead, it is the same as `max.operator=(vectorN)`, which simply causes `vector1` to be cleared and replaced by elements contained in `vectorN`, copying them.

Comment: That's why you should use a method... really. Early return saves the day here!

Answer (score 9):

Here's one solution (aside from Pesto's far-too-straightforward approach) - I've avoided `bind` and C++0x lambdas for explanatory purposes, but you could use them to remove the need for a separate function. I'm also assuming that with two vectors with an equal number of elements, which one is picked is irrelevant.

```
template <typename T> bool size_less (const T* lhs, const T* rhs) {
    return lhs->size() < rhs ->size();
}

void foo () {
    vector<T>* vecs[] = {&vec1, &vec2, &vec3, &vec4};
    vector<T>& vec = std::min_element(vecs, vecs + 4, size_less<vector<T> >);
}
```

Comment: Why not make 'vecs' also a std::vector, and use push_back to make it even more general?

Comment: @Konrad: So it can also be used with more (or less) than 4 vectors.

Comment: Yes, any container would work, but I picked an array because of the ease of initialization (thankfully C++0x will fix that). You could also just replace vecs + 4 with vecs + (sizeof(vecs) / sizeof(*vecs)) and extend the array to an arbitrary size.

Comment: @coppro: Instead of `vecs + 4` you might want to use `vecs + sizeof(vecs)/sizeof(vecs[0])`. And I would make `size_less` a function object, because those inline better.

Comment: @pkit: That would only make for more typing since all the vectors have a different name. You get hard-coded push_backs vs hard-coded array initializers. sbi has a good point, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my very simple method. Only interest is that you just need basic c++ to understand it.

```
 vector<T>* v[] = {&v1, &v2, &v3, &v4}, *max=&v1;
 for(int i=1; i < 4; ++i)
     if (v[i]->size() > max->size()) max = v[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of coppro's answer using a std::vector to reference any number of vectors for comparison.

```
template <typename T> bool size_less (const T* lhs, const T* rhs) {
    return lhs->size() < rhs ->size();
}

void foo () {
    // Define vector holding pointers to the original vectors
    typedef vector< vector<T>* > VectorPointers;

    // Fill the list
    VectorPointers vecs;
    vecs.push_back(&vec1);
    vecs.push_back(&vec2);
    vecs.push_back(&vec3);
    vecs.push_back(&vec4);        

    vector<T>& vec = std::min_element(
        vecs.begin(), 
        vecs.end(), 
        size_less<vector<T> >
    );
}
```

Comment: This buys you nothing over coppro's solution, except that it's less efficient (because it uses dynamic memory).

Answer (score 0):

I'm all for over-thinking stuff :)
For the general problem of finding the highest/lowest element in a group, I would use a priority_queue with a comparator:
(copying shamelessly from coppro, and modifying...)

```
template <typename T> bool size_less (const T* lhs, const T* rhs)
{
  return lhs->size() < rhs ->size();
}


vector* highest()
{
  priority_queue<vector<T>, size_less<T> > myQueue;
  ...
  ...
  return myQueue.top();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a std::multimap. That allows multiple entries with the same key.